# Comprehensive account of the Barnes G function?

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions

I am looking for a comprehensive account of the properties and applications of the Barnes G-Function. Everything from recurrence relations, proof of the infinite product representation, functional relations, e.t.c. Ideally with proofs?

I am primarily interested only on the detailed proof of it's infinite product representation and physical applications. Other proofs are a welcomed bonus for this beauty.

Comment: For me the infinite product representation is the *definition* of $G(z)$. What is your definition?

Comment: Interesting, I first came across the G function with the definition relating it to the hyperfactorial and gamma function for integer arguments, and then defined over the complex domain with the taylor series for $\log{G(z+1)}$?